# creating new user in couchdb 3 without admin password

Tags: couchdb, fauxton, couchdb-3.x

I just downloaded and installed CouchDB `v3`.

On first start, it prompted me to set an admin password which I did.

For the web app that I'm building, I want to use the CouchDB user authentication feature, so I created a new `_users` database using the Fauxton UI.

After creating the `_users` database I made a call to the REST API to insert a new user (this is the example code taken from the [documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/security.html#creating-a-new-user)):

```
$ curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:jan \
     -H "Accept: application/json" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"name": "jan", "password": "apple", "roles": [], "type": "user"}'
```

Instead of the expected response

```
{"ok":true,"id":"org.couchdb.user:jan","rev":..."}
```

I'm getting

```
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not authorized to access this db."}
```

When adding the admin credentials to the API call, it works as expected:

```
$ curl -X PUT http://admin:____@localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:jan \
     -H "Accept: application/json" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"name": "jan", "password": "apple", "roles": [], "type": "user"}'

{"ok":true,"id":"org.couchdb.user:jan","rev":"..."}
```

My question:

Are there any settings or permissions I can set to make the request work **without** having to add the admin credentials? (AFAIK this worked fine in `v2.x`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the fun of the good old Admin Party, which for many years was the default setting for CouchDB, meaning it was installed with *zero* security as everyone was effectively an admin.

From The Road to CouchDB 3.0: Security<sup>[1]</sup>

> One of the aspects of getting started easily was a 1.x-era choice to
>   make it easy to use CouchDB: the Admin Party. Admin Party means that,
>   by default, any request made against CouchDB was done in the context
>   of an admin user, i.e. you were allowed to do anything.

3.0 changed all of that by shutting down the Admin Party - what a bunch of buzz kills!

I suspect there are more sophisticated solutions, but for those that want to party on<sup>[2]</sup> quickly, minor changes to `etc/local.ini` and any permissions on `_users` will satisfy.

The key is the configuration property `require_valid_user`<sup>[3]</sup>.

In `etc/local.ini`, modify the `chttpd` and `couch_httpd_auth` sections

```
[chttpd]
require_valid_user = false

[couch_httpd_auth]
require_valid_user = false
```

That's all that is needed *unless* there are members and/or roles defined for the `_users` database. If there are, they must be deleted (easily with Fauxton).

After cleaning up members/roles and altering the `etc/local.ini` restart CouchDB and you should be able to create users without a problem.  Party on! 👍

Just be sure to consider the ramifications of such changes.

*Disclaimer - I don't recommend running CouchDB in any security context resembling Admin Party!*

---

<sup>1</sup> [The Road to CouchDB 3.0: Security](https://blog.couchdb.org/2020/02/26/the-road-to-couchdb-3-0-security/)
<sup>2</sup> [Party On](https://giphy.com/embed/d3mlYwpf96kMuFjO)
<sup>3</sup> [require_valid_user](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/auth.html#couch_httpd_auth/require_valid_user)

Comment: Quick question, what do you mean by `Disclaimer - I don't recommend running CouchDB in any security context resembling Admin Party!`

Comment: @TonyNgomana admin party means *everyone* operates at the level of an administrator, thus any random actor could connect to the server and visit havoc upon the system.

Comment: oh like delete the database, I see